# How to remove white spaces (\t, \n, \r, space) form the beginning and the end of a string in shell?

Tags: shell, ash

I want to  remove white spaces (\t, \n, \r, space) form the beginning and the end of a string if they exist

How to do that?

Is it possibe to that only with expressions like `${str#*}`?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using bash (which your idea of `${str#}` seems to suggest), then you can use this:

```
echo "${str##[[:space:]]}" # trim all initial whitespace characters
echo "${str%%[[:space:]]}" # trim all trailing whitespace characters
```

Answer (score 0):

You can say

```
sed -e 's/^[ \t\r\n]*//' -e 's/[ \t\r\n]*$//' <<< "string"
#         ^^^^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^
#         beginning            end of string
```

Or use `\s` to match tab and space if it is supported by your `sed` version.

Comment: `[[:space:]]` should work in any POSIX-compliant version of sed.

Comment: @TomFenech yes, it should, thanks. I did not use it because the user is tagging with the tag `ash` and I remember from his previous questions that he works with old systems, so I cannot rely on anything : )

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `sed` then:

```
echo "${str}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'
```